# Gradually reallocating of memory leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, realloc

I'm trying to append new values to c array of strings in another function, however I am able to add only three records, when I try to add fourth entry and so forth the error of segfault occurs, which tells me that I use wrong memory. As fas as I understand, I gradually on demand allocating memory as  **realloc(*array, array_length * sizeof(char*))** so it should go fine, but it doesn't. Also when I try to append new records in main() function it goes as expected fine with 10 records.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int array_length = 0;

void add(char **array, char *new)
{
    array_length++;
    array = realloc(*array, array_length * sizeof(char*));
    array[array_length-1] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char*));
    strcpy(array[array_length-1], new);
}

int main() 
{
    char **array = malloc (sizeof (*array));

    // First way
    add(&array, "first str");    // fine
    add(&array, "second str");   // fine
    add(&array, "third str");    // fine
    //add(&array, "fourth str"); // Segmentation fault (core dumped)    
    
    // Second way: 10 records successfully appended to array
    // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    // {
    //     array_length++;
    //     array = realloc(array, array_length * sizeof(char*));
    //     array[array_length-1] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char*));
    //     strcpy(array[array_length-1], "str");
    // }

    for (int i = 0; i < array_length; i++)
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
    
    for (int j = 0; j < array_length; j++)
        free(array[j]);
    free(array);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well ... first thing I noticed was a type mismatch. In `main()` you define `array` as `char**`, then pass its address (type `char***`) to `add()`, but this later function takes an argument of type `char**`.

Comment: In add you're setting array not *array, so the result of the realloc() is not saved to the passed-in pointer as is being lost inside the add() call.

Comment: If you enabled all warnings and errors, your compiler would have likely [already shown you where the problem is](https://godbolt.org/z/x9recd). First, your `array` in the main function should be of type `char **` if it's supposed to represent an array of strings of characters. Then you pass a pointer to this variable so that `realloc` can mutate it, so `add` must accept a `char ***`. Second, the syntax for `realloc` is `x = realloc(x, new_length);`, or in this case `*array = realloc(*array, ...)`.

Comment: @Groo, thanks for pointing out, but even with these changes, still segfault occurs on 4th element

Comment: @user3121023, it works if I change declaration of array from char **array = malloc (sizeof (*array)); to char ***array = malloc (sizeof (*array)); I suppose it's pointer to memory address of string by id? If I call add as add(array, "first str"); without supplying address of array. And freeing memory at the end leads to segfault again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to differentiate between `char*`, `char**` and `char***` in your `add` function. Perhaps a good way would be to name the parameter `pArray` to keep track of what's going on:

```
int array_length = 0;

void add(char *** pArray, const char * new_val)
{
    array_length++;

    // we are modifying the original 'array' variable, 
    // so we need to assign the result to *pArray
    // (also note the sizeof used here)
    *pArray = realloc(*pArray, array_length * sizeof(char**));

    // from now on, we don't need to mutate the original variable,
    // so dereference 'pArray' into 'array'
    char ** array = *pArray;
    array[array_length - 1] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy_s(array[array_length - 1], 49, new_val);
}
```

If you want to avoid the triple-star thingy, consider wrapping the array into a struct. This is also better because `array_length` shouldn't be a global variable.

For example:

```
typedef struct
{
    char ** array;
    size_t array_length;
}
string_list;

void add(string_list * s, const char * new_val)
{
    s->array_length++;
    s->array = realloc(s->array, s->array_length * sizeof(char**));

    s->array[s->array_length - 1] = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy_s(s->array[s->array_length - 1], 49, new_val);
}

void string_list_init(string_list * s)
{
    s->array = NULL;
    s->array_length = 0;
}
```

And then simply:

```
string_list s;
string_list_init(&s);

// First way
add(&s, "first str");    // fine
add(&s, "second str");   // fine
add(&s, "third str");    // fine
add(&s, "fourth str"); // Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```